# A strategy question regarding content types vs. basic pages plus taxonomy/tags

Tags: nodes

I'm having trouble deciding what makes more sense. I am building a somewhat simple site and so far it seems fairly straightforward to use the basic page content type for nearly everything and add a field for taxonomy (to associate the page with the categories of the main menu) and if needed, tags to further categorize the pages for various views and lists. But is that the best strategy? The end-user is going to have to remember to choose a taxonomy term for each page, and choose the right one. If a tag is needed, they are going to have to remember to add a tag and spell it correctly. People are notoriously unable to do simple things like this without making mistakes. So, would it be better to create separate content types for each main menu category, even if they basically are the same basic page content type? If I did separate content types, I wouldn't have to ask people to select an item in the main menu taxonomy. I would still have to ask them to tag some of the content types, but I could leave that field off for those content types that don't need tags. But then I'd be faced with having to instruct the end-user to select the correct content type before creating a new page.

What is your opinion? Is there a better strategy among these choices or perhaps even another choice I didn't consider?

Answer (score 0):

You could use radio buttons for your 'content type' taxonomy terms and make it required.  That way your user sees all the content types available and has to pick one.  For your free tagging, you might be able to use a module like [Active Tags](http://drupal.org/project/active_tags) to make it a bit more accurate as well.